# Customizing YouTube Player in iOS

Tags: ios, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I have an app that streams YouTube videos using the YTPlayerView by Youtube. I want to start customizing it (controls/ rotation) 
After a few days searching on the web i couldn't find an answer to this.

All i could find is using the JS/Ruby/HTML to alter the player. Does any one know of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

The player controls can be given in the dictionary described below and can have the values 0,1,2 check this link for the control functionality
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
  @"controls" : @0,
  @"playsinline" : @1,
  @"autohide" : @1,
  @"showinfo" : @0,
  @"modestbranding" : @1
};
[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:videoId playerVars:playerVars];
```